# unexpected behavior of linux malloc

Tags: linux, null, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<pthread.h>

#define BLOCKSIZE 1024*1024
// #define BLOCKSIZE 4096
int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    void *myblock = NULL;
    int count = 0;
    while (1)
    {
        myblock =  malloc(BLOCKSIZE);
        if (!myblock){
            puts("error"); break;
        }
        memset(myblock,1, BLOCKSIZE);
        count++;
    }
    printf("Currently allocated %d \n",count);
    printf("end");
    exit(0);
}
```

When  BLOCKSIZE  is 1024*1024.  All is ok.  Malloc return NULL, loop is break. Program print text and exit.
When BLOCKSIZE is 4096 
Malloc never returns NULL Program crash. => Out of memory , killed by kernel . 
Why?

Comment: malloc only returns NULL when it's unable to allocate memory. When you lower the block size, you're able to allocate all the blocks, and since you never free them, you get an OOM error.

Answer (score 2):

> It's pitch black, you are likely to be eaten by an OOM killer.

Linux has this thing called an [OOM killer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) which wanders about killing off processes when it finds memory allocation is *very* heavy. The selection of which process(es) to kill is based on certain properties of each process (such as one allocating a lot of memory being a prime candidate).

It does this, partly due to its optimistic memory allocation strategy (it will generally give you address space whether or not there's enough backing memory on devices for it, something known as overcommit).

It's likely in this case that, when allocating 1M at a time, an allocation fails before the OOM killer finds you. With 4K, you're discovered before the allocation routines decide you've had enough.

You can configure the OOM killer to leave you alone if that's your desire, by writing an adjustment value of `-17` to your `oom_adj` entry in `procfs`. It's not advisable unless you know what your doing since it puts other (perhaps more important) processes at risk. Other values from `-16` to `+15` adjust the likelihood that your process will be selected.

You can also turn off overcommit altogether by writing `vm.overcommit_memory=2` to `/etc/sysctl.conf` but that again can present problems in your environment.

Comment: Programmer:  Allocate memory.
Linux: What, with your bare hands?